# Is it possible to get a list of reopen requests or reopen votes?

Tags: support, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

I have just written [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69854010/how-can-the-datagridrow-of-a-datagrid-be-null). The question was closed as it was marked as a duplicate, but the proposal in the duplicate causes such a performance drop, that it becomes unusable.

Therefore I have launched a "Reopen" request, and I would like to follow what's happening with my reopen requests (I remember having launched "Reopen" requests before, but I have forgotten which question I have done this for).

While checking my profile (`All Actions` tab), I can see that I have written the question. I can also see that I have edited the question (marked at `revised`), but I don't see the "Reopen" request.

Does this mean that it is not possible to see the list of questions, where I have launched a "Reopen" request? In case it is possible, how can I see that list?

Comment: If you go to your profile's vote's page, there is an option to see your reopen votes. As you're a 10K user, I *suspect* your "meaningful edit" would also be a reopen vote.

Comment: @SurajRao: it was a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: @Larnu: thanks for your reply. I indeed find the information on that page.

Comment: @Larnu: the reason for not finding it was that I regarded a "Reopen" request as an action, not as a vote. I modified the title of this question accordingly.

Comment: @Larnu a meaningful edit used to just add the question in the reopen queue. It didn't actually cast a reopen vote. Confusingly, casting a reopen vote *removed* the item from the reopen queue. However. this has been changed recently - now when making edits on closed questions, you need to explicitly opt into marking it for reopen. Edits no longer automatically do it.

Comment: Yes, @VLAZ, this is why I intentionally mentioned the "meaningful" edit feature.

Comment: Well, I did add more information in the question before pressing the "reopen" button :-)

Comment: The review can't be accessed directly until it is completed, unless you're a moderator or find it in the review queue.